How to Replace Default Flutter Icon with Custom Icon on Firebase-hosted Website?
I'm working on a Flutter web project, and I've hosted the site using Firebase. Everything works fine, but I'm struggling to replace the default Flutter icon that appears in the browser tab with my custom icon.

What I've Done:
Created Custom Icons: I have created custom icons in different sizes and formats:
Icon-192.png
Icon-512.png
Icon-maskable-192.png
Icon-maskable-512.png
Updated manifest.json: Here's my manifest.json file:
    "name": "my_journey",
    "short_name": "my_journey",
    "start_url": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "theme_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "description": "A new Flutter project.",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-maskable-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-maskable-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
}

Replaced Icons in the web/icons Directory: I have placed the icons in the web/icons directory.
Cleared Browser Cache: I've cleared my browser cache and even tried accessing the site in incognito mode, but the default Flutter icon still appears.
Rebuilt and Redeployed: I ran flutter build web and redeployed the project to Firebase, but the issue persists.
Despite following the above steps, the custom icon does not replace the default Flutter icon in the browser tab. What could I be missing? Is there something specific to Firebase hosting or Flutter that I need to configure differently?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Attachments:
Here is one of the icons I am trying to use:

PS: The site is hard to be fount on Google so I will paste the link and some meta if needed
<meta name="description" content="My Journey: An AI-driven online diary for productivity and self-discovery. Record your goals and reflections, and stay motivated on your path to success.">
<meta name="keywords" content="productivity, self-discovery, AI diary, My Journey, online diary">

